# how to do a client side redirect in angular $http?

Tags: angularjs

I use following code to do a redirect after $http post:

```
   $http({
      method  : 'POST',
      url     : '/response',
      data    : querystring.stringify($scope.formData),
      headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } 
    })
      .success(function(data) {
        // the data is ('<html><head><META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=https://www.example.com/"></head>'
        $window.location.replace(data);
    }
```

})

the $window.location.replace is not working, any idea how to achieve the redirect as requested by the response from the server? thanks.

Comment: Can you change the server's behavior? It's unfortunate that it's responding with HTML.

Comment: This is a major code smell here.  The server should never care what the client UI is doing, you will have some major coupling issues with this strategy.

Comment: seems a regular form submit should work, but is there a way to intercept the submit event before it's finally post? I put a onClick event, but not got called at all.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [AngularJS Developer Guide on Using $location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/%24location), try:

```
$location.path('/someNewPath');
$location.replace();
```

Comment: the issue is, the response from the server is a http text, which might contains META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh"…, if we do a regular form submit, the response will redirect it to the correct url, but in $http post, it does not do that.

Comment: AJAX requests are really *not* supposed to redirect. Usually, you handle your redirection logic in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

redirecting to the same domain, you should use as in @Emanuel Saringan 's comment. However, u should try:
 `angular.element(document.location = "your link")`
when redirecting to different domain.